# Visual Studio doesn't register "DragDrop" function moving string from one list to another

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, drag-and-drop

As the title implies, I have a form that populates three list from uploaded spreadsheets. Each line item is converted into its own string, and the user needs to be able to grab a string, and drag it from one list to another.

While MouseDown registers to grab the string, DragLeave registers to remove the string from its original list, and DragEnter registers to drop the string in a new list, I cannot get DragDrop to work. It is already set up in for the list like so:

```
this.lstCKWMissingJobs.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.lstCKWMissingJobs_DragEnter);
this.lstCKWMissingJobs.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.lstCKWMissingJobs_DragDrop);
this.lstCKWMissingJobs.DragLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.lstCKWMissingJobs_DragLeave);
this.lstCKWMissingJobs.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.lstCKWMissingJobs_MouseDown);
```

Comment: I'm guessing by "list" you mean a `ListBox`?  MouseDown is only half the action for a drag-drop Windows users are familiar with.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]; the code inside some of those methods would be more appropriate to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with drag and drop functions. When a drag operation is performed if you don't assign the effect another value it will be at [None by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter(v=vs.110).aspx).

To change the effect, you can assign it in the DragEnter event handler.

```
private void yourDragEnterHandler(object sender, DragEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```